# C# With XmlWriter write "d3p1:string" element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

```
<Messages xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <d3p1:string>sample string 1</d3p1:string>
      <d3p1:string>sample string 2</d3p1:string>
    </Messages>
```

With `XmlWriter` I woul dlike to write this `XML`

Code:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("Messages");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "d3p1", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");

writer.WriteElementString("d3p1:string", "my message");

writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Problem is that

```
  writer.WriteElementString("d3p1:string", "my message");
```

is not valid.

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
>   name.

How to write `d3p1:string` xml tag?

Comment: xmlns cannot be written with WriteAttributeString you will have to add that via the namespaces option. That is most likely the reason it fails to write you element.

Comment: xmlns works correct. Problem is with d3p1:string. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also use the namespace and prefix at WriteElementString:

```
const string ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays";
const string prefix = "d3p1";
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create("file.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Messages");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", prefix, null, ns);
    writer.WriteElementString(prefix, "string", ns, "my message");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I needed to write:

```
<t xml:space="preserve">
```

The code that did it was:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "preserve")
```